# Wordpress plugin - Event List Calendar - doesn't use it's own stylesheet

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugins, calendar

After installing the Event List Calendar plugin it doesn't look like it should. It looks like it is completely deprived of CSS stylesheet:

http://www.tohajduk.com/wp

And it should look like this:

https://s.w.org/plugins/event-list-calendar/screenshot-3.png?r=1223722

In the twenty-fourteen theme looks fine. When I deleted all of the content (styles and html) it still looks like this. Can anyone help pls?

Comment: It looks like the CSS isn't loading from the plugin:

`/plugins/event-list-calendar/assets/css/event-list-cal.css` - Can you check to see if that file exists?

Comment: Yes, the file exist in this path. In the other theme the plugin works fine, only in mine somehow it doesn't see it's own stylesheet. Thanks!

Comment: It could be possible that the theme is unenqueing the CSS. Do you have anything in your theme functions that could be responsible for removing it?

Comment: Even when i deleted all of the content files (in html and css sections) and left the plugin code, still looks like this. Where else can it be?